# Jasmine - Testing if Controller Exists Getting Error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

i have a simple controller:

```
app.controller("RegisterController", function ($scope, $location) {

    // Do something

});
```

And all i am trying to do is to test this controller is defined:

```
describe('RegisterController', function() {

    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;

        $controller('RegisterController', {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $scope});
    }));

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect($controller).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

And i get the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to test the wrong thing, you don't want to test $controller which is just a service in ngMock, which is used to test your own controller.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$controller

basically you need to create the controller using this service. I have created a plunkr example.
http://plnkr.co/edit/DQZGZERfCptAlgeBUUqb?p=preview

now if you change the name of the controller to RegisterController1 the test will fail, hope this helps.
`

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("RegisterController", function ($rootScope, $scope) {

    // Do something

});

describe('RegisterController', function() {

    var $rootScope, $scope, $controller,registerController;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller = _$controller_;

        registerController = $controller('RegisterController', {'$rootScope' : $rootScope, '$scope': $scope});
    }));

    it('should exist', function() {
        expect(registerController).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="jasmine@2.2.1" data-semver="2.2.1" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.css" />
    <script data-require="jasmine@2.2.1" data-semver="2.2.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine@2.2.1" data-semver="2.2.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jasmine@2.2.1" data-semver="2.2.1" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.2.1/boot.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-mocks@1.3.14" data-semver="1.3.14" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```